# Bash terminal shows: "update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for javac" on start and when I try to run a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash

Title pretty much says it.  Every time I open a terminal, I get the message: "update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for javac".  I have no idea what this means, maybe something with Java?  This is a mild annoyance, however, when I try to run a bash script (i.e. updating terminal with `source .bashrc`) it gives that message again and does absolutely nothing.

Anybody had this problem before or know how to solve it?

Comment: It suggests you've added an `update-alternatives` command to your ~/.bashrc file - you will need to open it in a text editor and remove or comment out the offending command

Comment: That's it.  Thanks a lot.  Apparently it was added in their for NativeScript.  That's annoying.  I appreciate the help.